# The byte[] obtained with the array() method of ByteBuffer created with allocateDirect is not direct

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

I tried using ByteBuffer to slice the byte[] data. The overall process is as follows.

1. Allocate ByteBuffer using allocateDirect. Add byte[] of allocated ByteBuffer to buffer queue of data processing class.
2. The data processing class stores the result in the buffer and returns it as a callback.
3. In the callback, wrap the received byte[] with ByteBuffer again, and slice() it to call the native method.

The sliced ​​data is transmitted to native code through the jni interface. In this case, jni requires that the ByteBuffer is allocated directly. The problem is that if I get byte[] through the array() method and wrap it in a ByteBuffer, it is no longer direct state. Is there a way to keep the ByteBuffer in direct state in this case? Or is there a workaround to avoid using memory copy? I don't want to use memory copy because of performance issues.

Here is minimal code sample.

```
ByteBuffer[] directBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bufferSize);

if (directBuffer.isDirect()) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Direct buffer!");
} else {
   Log.i(TAG, "Non direct buffer!");
}

ByteBuffer test = ByteBuffer.wrap(directBuffer.array());
if (test.isDirect()) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Direct buffer!");
} else {
   Log.i(TAG, "Non direct buffer!");
}
```

Result

```
Direct buffer!
Non direct buffer!
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no such thing as a direct byte array. You need to put the data back into the original direct buffer, or into a new one.

Comment: Thanks Marquis, I just solved it by adding a native function that does what I wanted.